# Region growing algorithm giving improper results

Tags: matlab

I am applying the region-growing algorithm to segment tumors in breast images. The image on the left side is the original image. The brightest spot in the center should be the tumor. The segmentation should only display that spot. However, after applying the algorithm, the resultant image is that on the right side which is not accurate. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
I = rgb2gray(im2double(imread('TM25.jpg')));
J=imadjust(I,[],[],0.5);
J=imgaussfilt(J);
J= regiongrowing(J, 64, 64,0.5);
imshowpair(I,J,'montage')
```

[image]

```
function J=regiongrowing(I,x,y,reg_maxdist)
% This function performs "region growing" in an image from a specified
% seedpoint (x,y)
%
% J = regiongrowing(I,x,y,t) 
% 
% I : input image 
% J : logical output image of region
% x,y : the position of the seedpoint (if not given uses function getpts)
% t : maximum intensity distance (defaults to 0.2)
%
% The region is iteratively grown by comparing all unallocated neighbouring pixels to the region. 
% The difference between a pixel's intensity value and the region's mean, 
% is used as a measure of similarity. The pixel with the smallest difference 
% measured this way is allocated to the respective region. 
% This process stops when the intensity difference between region mean and
% new pixel become larger than a certain treshold (t)
%
% Example:
%
% I = im2double(imread('medtest.png'));
% x=198; y=359;
% J = regiongrowing(I,x,y,0.2); 
% figure, imshow(I+J);
%
% Author: D. Kroon, University of Twente

if(exist('reg_maxdist','var')==0), reg_maxdist=0.2; end
if(exist('y','var')==0), figure, imshow(I,[]); [y,x]=getpts; y=round(y(1)); x=round(x(1)); end

J = zeros(size(I)); % Output 
Isizes = size(I); % Dimensions of input image

reg_mean = I(x,y); % The mean of the segmented region
reg_size = 1; % Number of pixels in region

% Free memory to store neighbours of the (segmented) region
neg_free = 10000; neg_pos=0;
neg_list = zeros(neg_free,3); 

pixdist=0; % Distance of the region newest pixel to the regio mean

% Neighbor locations (footprint)
neigb=[-1 0; 1 0; 0 -1;0 1];
diff = 01;
% Start regiogrowing until distance between regio and posible new pixels become
% higher than a certain treshold
while(pixdist<reg_maxdist && reg_size<numel(I) && diff ~=0)
    num1 = sum(sum(reg_size));
    % Add new neighbors pixels
    for j=1:4,
        % Calculate the neighbour coordinate
        xn = x +neigb(j,1); yn = y +neigb(j,2);
        
        % Check if neighbour is inside or outside the image
        ins=(xn>=1)&&(yn>=1)&&(xn<=Isizes(1))&&(yn<=Isizes(2));
        
        % Add neighbor if inside and not already part of the segmented area
        if(ins&&(J(xn,yn)==0)) 
                neg_pos = neg_pos+1;
                neg_list(neg_pos,:) = [xn yn I(xn,yn)]; J(xn,yn)=1;
        end
    end

    % Add a new block of free memory
    if(neg_pos+10>neg_free), neg_free=neg_free+10000; neg_list((neg_pos+1):neg_free,:)=0; end
    
    % Add pixel with intensity nearest to the mean of the region, to the region
    dist = abs(neg_list(1:neg_pos,3)-reg_mean);
    [pixdist, index] = min(dist);
    J(x,y)=2; reg_size=reg_size+1;
    
    % Calculate the new mean of the region
    reg_mean= (reg_mean*reg_size + neg_list(index,3))/(reg_size+1);
    
    % Save the x and y coordinates of the pixel (for the neighbour add proccess)
    x = neg_list(index,1); y = neg_list(index,2);
    
    % Remove the pixel from the neighbour (check) list
    neg_list(index,:)=neg_list(neg_pos,:); neg_pos=neg_pos-1;
    num2 = sum(sum(reg_size));
    diff = num2-num1;
end

% Return the segmented area as logical matrix
J=J>1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Region growing is a very simple algorithm. In short, it says "If the next pixels is less than `reg_maxdist` in pixel value than the current pixel, its part of the region, otherwise its not".

Your image is very smooth. That means that pixel values change slowly in adjacent pixels, thus region growing algorithms will take them in. You can always toy with the maximum allowed pixel difference a bit (0 is all pixels need to be the same value, 1 is all pixels are part of the region), and hope for a better outcome, but you are not guaranteed to get a good result.

For your image, I am 99% sure region growing won't cut it and you will need to use more sophisticated algorithms.